# Syntax sugar for signal slot

Tags: c++, c++11, signals-slots

Recently I searched internet for good signal-slot library and wonder why on Earth we need such a cumbersome syntax for connecting member methods to signals?

Usually we have to write something like this:

```
mySignal.connect(&MyClassName::myMethodName, this);
```

or like that:

```
mySignal += std::bind(&MyClassName::myMethodName, this, std::placeholders::_1);
```

There is obvious duplication and unnessesary typing. Is it possible in modern C++ to implement such functionality in, for example, C# way:

```
mySignal += myMethodName
```

and automatically capture pointer to member function and this pointer from context?

Comment: Try declaring `myMethodName` as a free standing function.  This will remove the typing of the class name & scope operator.  Otherwise, take a keyboarding class or write a program to generate these statements.

Comment: Where would you put such a line ? I.e, what's the type of `this` ?

Comment: Yeah, it's a way to go for someone. Fortunately good guys in c++ committee invent things like auto and lambdas instead of forcing others to take keyboard classes. I just wonder what prevents them to simplify this thing. this is a MyClassName variable.

Comment: With lambdas (and the fact that C++ doesn't force everything to be part of a class) it is far less common to have to create a whole class just to have a special method for the thread code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible in modern C++ to implement such functionality in, for example, C# way? [...]

No, that's not possible in C++. The syntax for taking the address of a member function requires qualifying the function name with the class name (i.e. `&MyClassName::myMethodName`).

If you don't want to specify the class name, one possibility is to use lambdas. In particular, if you can afford a C++14 compiler, generic lambdas allow writing:

```
mySignal.connect([this] (auto x) -> { myMethodName(x) });
```

Sadly, you can't get much terser than this. You can use default lambda capture to save some syntactic noise:

```
mySignal.connect([&] (auto x) -> { myMethodName(x) });
```

However, Scott Meyers warns against the pitfalls of default lambda capture modes in his new book *Effective Modern C++*. From the readability point of view, I'm not sure this improves things a lot compared to your first option.

Besides, things soon become awkward if you want your lambda to perfectly forward its argument(s) to `myMethodName`:

```
mySignal.connect([&] (auto&& x) -> { myMethodName(std::forward<decltype(x)>(x)) });
```

If you don't mind macros (I usually do), you can employ a preprocessor-based solution [as suggested by Quentin in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28398551/1932150). However, I would prefer using a perfect-forwarding lambda in that case:

```
#define SLOT(name) \
        [this] (auto&&... args) { name (std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...); }
```

Which you could use like so:

```
e.connect(SLOT(foo));
```

Here is a [*live demo on Coliru*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d5ff31eab8cd993).

Comment: I see. Do you know  what C++ compilers lacks that prevents us to implement clean syntax?

Comment: @Rem: I'm not a language designer so I'm not sure what the implications would be.

Comment: @Rem You shall pass an object to call the the non-static member function on. C# handles that differently, as you can see in delegates.

Comment: @Ream: there have been various proposals and talk about "lifting expressions" (if I recall the name properly) that would address this. The C++ language requires that member functions be associated with a specific type, which either requires calling it (possibly with the implicit `this`) or qualifying it with the class name. If the standard allowed the syntax you want, compilers would handle it. One such proposal: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3617.htm

Answer (score 2):

Shall the preprocessor have a shot at it ?

```
#include <type_traits>
#define CONNECT(method) \
    connect(&std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(this)>::method, this)
```

Cane be used as follows :

```
mySignal.CONNECT(myMethodName);
```

Comment: Sure, it's a way to go. Unfortunately this syntax leads to internal compiler error C1001 in VS2013

Comment: @Rem Come on, VC++ :(